# How to run my plugin only when the whole page is sent?

Tags: plugins

Currently for each page, my plugin runs several times.

For instance, when accessing a page in admin panel, it runs 3 times since there is 3 requests.

1. post.php
2. admin-ajax.php
3. admin-ajax.php

How can it make run only for the relevant request (here it's post.php)?

I hope there's a wordpress way which doesn't force me to know and inspect the url myself.

I hook functions at several points.
The real deal happens in admin_enqueue_scripts, admin_notices, add_meta_boxes, save_post, delete_post, the_post, wp_enqueue_scripts, wp_footer. Some common logic happen in plugins_loaded, shutdown.

It's important because when my plugin encounter an error, it displays an error message the next (and only the real next) time the plugin runs.

**All I want to do is to run code when page are actually displayed to the user**

I don't want to run the same code when the page is not displaued to the user (redirection/output cleared/output sent to outer space/...).

Comment: To what/where is your plugin hooked into?

Comment: The real deal happens in admin_enqueue_scripts, admin_notices, add_meta_boxes, save_post, delete_post, the_post, wp_enqueue_scripts, wp_footer. Some common logic happen in plugins_loaded, shutdown.

Comment: Basically what @Cybmeta said below should help :D

Comment: I'm sorry but you don't know what you need or what exactly your problem is, so I can not help you. I've deleted the answer util you elaborate your problem.